# Adding one day to the "Fri May 10 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0800" and get the final answer also in the same format using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I have input type date and allowing user to select a date from the calendar. then I want to add another day to the selected date using angularjs. The final date should also be in the same format of the date selected by the user. Following depicts the format of the date selected by the user

```
Fri May 10 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)
```

How can I achieve this? I tried using the `x.getDate() + 1` . But that provides a different format.

Comment: `getDate()` only returns the day component of a date. For your example date, it would be the value `10`. You probably want `x.setDate(x.getDate() + 1)` to add a day to the date `x`.

Comment: But this provides the output as milliseconds.

Comment: Then box it up with another `Date` constructor call: `new Date(x)`.

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x = new Date();
console.log(x.toString());

x.setDate(x.getDate()+1);
console.log(x.toString());
```

For more information, see

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0):

For adding date:

```
var date = new Date()
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)
console.log(date)
```

For adding month

```
var date = new Date()
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1)
console.log(date)
```

See more about date instance https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date